# Collage of images in android

Tags: android, image, android-image

**What I want:**

I want to create an Android application to create a collage of images.
Multiple images should be able to move, zoom and rotate on touch.

**What I tried:**

Tried this in `custom view`, `surface view`, `matrix manipulation` and by
adding image views in the activity. (I have tried to achieve this in
many ways, but every time it stuck at a point) Seen so many ways on
the internet, but all of them allow a single image to perform all these, I'm
unable to do this with multiple images.

Can anyone please guide me the correct direction to achieve this? Whether by any of the ways I mentioned above or some other way?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [application](https://github.com/wsanville/modified-multitouch-controller) for showing multiple images in single activity with gestures.

There are two arrays of images in `PhotoSortrView` class.

Remove comment from 1st IMAGE array and comment 2nd one.

Comment: project is moved to this link https://github.com/lukehutch/android-multitouch-controller